# CDash - Installation, I can't register in CDash/install.php after following the documentation

Tags: php, mysql, lamp, cdash

I am currently trying to install CDash 2.4.0 on Linux 16.04. At first I downloaded the newest version:

```
cd /var/www/html
sudo git clone https://github.com/Kitware/CDash.git
```

Then I created config.local.php:

```
cd /var/www/html/CDash/config
sudo cp config.php config.local.php
```

After that I removed the code after /* DON'T CHANGE AFTER THIS LINE*/ and added the password for MySQL Database.

I have also created cdash user with following commands:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
<HERE YOU TYPE YOUR MYSQL ROOT PASSWORD>

mysql> create database cdash;
mysql> create user 'cdash'@'localhost' identified by '<YOUR_PASSWORD_GOES_HERE>';
mysql> grant all privileges on cdash.* to 'cdash'@'localhost' with grant option;
```

Documentation states that after completing these steps I should be able to register opening /localhost/CDash/install.php, but I see nothing but a blank page.

I have already checked if I didn't install any php extenstions that I saw in documentation, but this is not the case.

Thanks in advance for your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Move the CDash install up a directory like /var/www ( /var/www/CDash )

Create a soft link to CDash/public ( ln -s /var/www/CDash/public /var/www/html/CDash )

install the php-mbstring package in addition to the ones listed as dependencies.

Then go to host/CDash/install.php in your browser.

I just figured this out today :)